# Keeping the window in dialog

Tags: linux, perl, dialog

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
#WINDOW 1
system ("dialog --keep-window --menu Customize 10 70 50 'Flush rules' 'Clear all the rules' 2> /tmp/customize.txt ");
open FILE4, "/tmp/customize.txt" or die $!;
     chomp(my $customize = <FILE4>);
           if($customize =~ /Flush rules/){
           `iptables -F`;
           system ("dialog --infobox 'All tables have been flushed.' 05 35");
           }
           else{
               exit;
           }
```

When the above code is executed then a dialog box appears which shows an option to flush rules. When I press Enter the command `iptables -F` executes and it flushes all the iptables rules. After that the program terminates. I want that after flushing all the rules the window which came in starting i.e which gives the option to flush rules should not close. The program should not terminate after flushing the rules. It should come back to the **window1**.

Comment: What's the benefit of Perl here anyway?  I like Perl, but this looks like a shell script afflicted by a horrible alien disease.

Comment: This is a part of my perl code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about surrounding it with:

```
while (1)
{
     #WINDOW 1
     ... rest of program
}
```

You could add an exit option to the dialog box and have break the while loop when that option is chosen.

Comment: I knew that but I thought there will be some option like --keep-window

Answer (score 0):

While `dialog` makes this very easy, it is not the most flexible solution.  A proper GUI application would have a single window whose appearance changes in response to user interactions via callbacks.  There are plenty of tools to do this from Perl; if you are on GTK, look at gtkperl.  Or look at http://perl-begin.org/uses/GUI/